# Operating and rationalizing surds

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can someone show me the methodology for dealing with such operations of surds as these:

[image: surdoperations]

The question is to express as a **single** fraction with a rational denominator.

I would post my working out, but it has absolutely no link to the answer, and it's because I have never been taught how to solve these types of questions before. If you could explain to me the methodology for solving these and how you did it, it would be very much helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}} -\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) - 3\sqrt{2} + 3\sqrt{3}}{(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})
(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})}$$

Apply $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$

I think you can take it from here?

Comment: Can you please explain what you did?

Comment: @Brett $$\frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad-bc}{bd}$$ You know how to take the LCM?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what you did in the answer. Did you multiply everything by the same expression? It seems that you just combined the denominator, and I'm not sure what you did with the numerator.

Comment: @Brett No. I multiplied the $\sqrt{2}$ in the first fraction by $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$,i.e the denominator of second fraction. Like you see $ad$ in my example. Similarly I multiplied $3$ by $\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$. Get it now? And the denominator is $(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ which simplifies to $2-3 = -1$

Comment: OK, thanks I see it clearly now. Regarding the rule you posted in wherein a/b - c/d = ad-bc / bd, does this rule apply to all fractions, even when you add? eg a/b + c/d = ad + bc / bd ?

Comment: @Brett yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

To the comment, you can see this by noticing, for $b,d \not = 0$

\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{b} \pm \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{d}{d}\right) \pm \frac{c}{d}\left(\frac{b}{b}\right) = \frac{ ad \pm bc}{bd}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to rationalize the denominator of each term separately.

$$\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2-\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt2(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)}{(\sqrt2-\sqrt3)(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)}=\frac{2+\sqrt6}{2-3}$$

Again, $$\frac3{\sqrt2+\sqrt3}=\frac{3(\sqrt2-\sqrt3)}{(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)(\sqrt2-\sqrt3)}=\frac{3\sqrt2-3\sqrt3}{2-3}$$