# How do I solve operations involving fractional surds?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to know how to **independently** solve operations involving fractional surds such as this:

[image]

How do I logically figure out how to do each one? I can do some of them, but not all of them. Do I treat them as a normal fraction and just try and add them up? is their a 'trick' ? If I can do normal operations with fractions, should I be able to do these?

Comment: Follow this (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707905/operating-and-rationalizing-surds/707947#707947)

Comment: I believe this question should be closed as duplicate of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/707905/154545) (posted 2 hours earlier by OP). They describe the same problem and all answers are useful for both questions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for a fraction that resembles  $\frac{a}{\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}}$, you could multiply it by $\frac{\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{c}}$ (which is equal to $1$) to cause the denominator to become a rational number. For this reason, this process is known as "rationalizing" the expression.

So for example, $$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5}} &= \frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{14} + \sqrt{21} + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15}}{7 - 5}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot(\sqrt{14} + \sqrt{21} + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15})\end{align}$$

For your questions, you might try combining each of them into a single fraction. Some of them automatically gets rationalized (e.g. (a) and (b)). Otherwise if the denominator of the result is not a rational number, you can then go ahead to "rationalize" the resultant expression as described above.

Comment: But do this after you have found a common denominator using normal fraction manipulation

Comment: @DaleM I see no reason why not rationalize before adding the fractions.